# How to block fake Googlebots?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I guess a fake Googlebot visited my site. Here is the entry log:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
66.249.73.72
```

I think like that because it crawled some addresses that do not exist! actually, they had been created by me at all

the fake bot has some stracture, it adds a spicefic word to first of my URLs
for instance
this page is exist

```
https://stackoverflow.com/user
```

but the bot crawled :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/some-word-user
https://stackoverflow.com/some-word-jobs
```

and here my robots.txt.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search?q=*
Disallow: *?replytocom
Disallow: /*add-to-cart=*
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Sitemap: -----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First you should know, googlebot crawls not existing addresses too,
   i.e. on trying to discover new content.
2. Second, i personally would better live with fake googlebots, as to
   risk to exclude googlebot per its IP. [Google adds new IPs to
   googlebot](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/4fKthSy7oFQ/GgslLXJnDQAJ). Again: don't risk it.

Comment: thank you for your reply. If I do not block it, does it affect SEO?

Comment: noway! It *could* make your server last a bit higher. It *could* influence a bit your analytics numbers. But SEO - noway. What you maybe should think about is: why they scrape your site? Maybe content theft? Look into it. Maybe they create mirrors? Look into it. And don't hesitate to rise a removal request - read here about it: https://support.google.com/legal/answer/3110420

Comment: @joei you can establish a kind of check routine, like Google describes here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553 . Try to not do this not for any and every request - but try to chain it to something like `if(preg_match('/Googlebot\//i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])`

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Googlebot searches always come from a Googlebot IP address as in crawl-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.googlebot.com
So a possible method is to check that if the agent includes Googlebot/2.1 AND the remote includes googlebot.com then it is valid. If not then it's a fake.

Here is the code -

```
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$remote = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] : gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$value = "googlebot";
$pos1 = strpos(strtolower($remote),$value);
$pos2 = strpos(strtolower($agent),$value);
if ($pos1===false && $pos2>0) {
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'errorpage.php');
  exit();
}
```